# Calculate fragment 3D distance to line

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I want to draw a polyline with glDrawElements and GL_LINES in OpenGL ES3 with a preset line pixel width. For every generated fragment, I want to calculate the perpendicular 3D distance between the fragment and the line segment that produced it in the fragment shader.

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Regards

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: A 3D distance to a fragment? Fragments don't exist in space. Do you mean a point on your projection plane? Or do you also want to include the calculated depth for that fragment?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It seems to me that if the fragment was generated by the line it's distance to the line would be 0? Can you explain a bit more *why* you want to do this?

Comment: I am able to use the 2D position of the fragment to sample a texture representing a heightmap that gives me a 3D position of the fragment. Thinking about it, getting the 2D perpendicular distance of the fragment to the line that creates it would be enough to derive the 3D distance from it.